# Is it Safe to use an Unfiltered $_GET Variable within the Switch Function?

Tags: php, security

How safe is it to use an unfiltered `$_GET` variable directly within a switch function as shown in the example below?

```
<?php

 switch ($_GET['sort'])
 {
  case "price":
  // Do something
  break;

  default:
  // Do something else
  break;
 }

?>
```

Is it possible to compromise the security of my application if the `$_GET` variable only appears within this switch function throughout the entire PHP script?

**ADD: For that matter, will an unfiltered $_GET variable cause a comparison operation to fail in a catastrophic manner?**

Comment: case is a string comparison 'a' == 'b'; looks safe to me, just make sure the 'default' is meaningful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to test values from `$_GET` in a switch. That's validation in and of itself. The danger is when you let that value work its way into a filesystem path, or database query, or HTML block, or (shudder) eval'd code without context-appropriate sanitization.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for pointing out that switch is a form of validation.

Answer (score 1):

It is only unsafe to use the result of `_GET` or `_POST`, or any other data set by a user in code executed by an external program (e.g. queries and `exec()` calls).  Echoing data received from a user is also unsafe if not encoded.

In other words what you are doing is fine.

Comment: bear in mind that inserting user-data into a file or output stream also means that it has the potential to be executed by something.